# obtener el total de venta de productos por categorias entre 3 tablas en mysql

Tags: mysql

En MYSQL quiero obtener las "Categorias" con el "total" de productos vendidos.
Por ejemplo

```
Cant | Categoria
--------------------
5    | Hamburguesas
4    | Papas
0    | Refrescos
```

Tengo las tablas "Categorias", "Productos", "Ticket"

En Categorias:

```
ID | Categoria
------------------
1  | Hamburguesas
2  | Papas
3  | Refrescos
```

En Productos:

```
ID | ID_CATEGORIA | Producto
----------------------------------
1  | 1            | Hamburguesa x1
2  | 1            | Hamburguesa x2
3  | 1            | Hamburguesa x3
4  | 2            | Papas x1
5  | 2            | Papas x2
6  | 2            | Papas x3
7  | 3            | Refresco x1
8  | 3            | Refresco x2
```

En Ticket:

```
ID | ID_TICKET | ID_PRODUCTO
-----------------------------
1  | 1         | 2
2  | 1         | 4
3  | 2         | 1
4  | 3         | 2
5  | 3         | 3
6  | 3         | 4
7  | 4         | 6
8  | 4         | 5
9  | 4         | 1
```

He tratado de hacer consultas con INNER JOIN pero sigo sin obtener el resultado esperado. Agradezco su ayuda

**EDITO**

La siguinte consulta me muestra los totales del primer producto de cada categoria

```
SELECT cp.id, cp.nombre, prods.productos, tpx.cantidad FROM categorias_producto AS cp 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS productos, p.id, p.id_categoria FROM producto AS p GROUP BY p.id_categoria ) AS prods ON prods.id_categoria = cp.id
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT COUNT(tp.id) AS cantidad, tp.id_producto FROM ticket_producto AS tp GROUP BY tp.id_producto ) AS tpx ON tpx.id_producto = prods.id
WHERE cp.id > 1
```

La ultima condicion solo es para no mostrar mi primer categoria.

Comment: Por favor, muéstranos qué has intentado... y pásanos el dataset en SQL para poder reproducir tu pregunta

Comment: Debemos asumir que las cantidades siempre son *1*. Por lo tanto, los datos de la venta lo tienes en `ticket`, los datos de la categoría del producto están dentro de `productos` y el nombre de la categoría está en la tabla `categorias`. Con `INNER JOIN` obtienes los resultados, o con subconsultas. Muéstranos la consulta que has generado para poder ver donde está tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que estás buscando sería algo así:

```
SELECT IFNULL(Cant,0) Cant,nombre Categoria
  FROM categorias_producto cp
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID_CATEGORIA,COUNT(*) Cant
      FROM ticket_producto
      JOIN producto p ON ID_PRODUCTO=p.ID
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 ON cp.ID=ID_CATEGORIA;
```

Pues es la que devuelve la salida que indicas en tu pregunta:

```
+------+--------------+
| Cant | Categoria    |
+------+--------------+
|    5 | Hamburguesas |
|    4 | Papas        |
|    0 | Refrescos    |
+------+--------------+
```

Con respecto a tu intento, agrupas antes de combinar y este concepto es clave para esta consulta: en el ticket únicamente tienes productos, aún no sabes a qué categoría pertenece cada uno. De igual forma, en las categorías puedes saber cuántos productos hay en cada categoría, pero aún no puedes saber cuántos productos de cada categoría han sido vendidos. En este caso, antes va el `JOIN` y después el `GROUP BY`. Al contrario no sale.

En tu respuesta sí que agrupas después de combinar, aunque el resultado que obtienes tiene un formato diferente al que pides, parece haber sido obtenido de otro dataset, y los campos con los que trabajas no son los que has facilitado en la pregunta. En futuras ocasiones, aporta el dataset en SQL, así nos facilitarás la respuesta:

```
CREATE TABLE categorias_producto (
  ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(31)
);
CREATE TABLE producto (
  ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_CATEGORIA INT(11),
  Producto VARCHAR(31)
);
CREATE TABLE ticket_producto (
  ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_TICKET INT(11),
  ID_PRODUCTO INT(11)
);
INSERT INTO categorias_producto VALUES
(1, 'Hamburguesas'),
(2, 'Papas'),
(3, 'Refrescos');
INSERT INTO producto VALUES
(1, 1, 'Hamburguesa x1'),
(2, 1, 'Hamburguesa x2'),
(3, 1, 'Hamburguesa x3'),
(4, 2, 'Papas x1'),
(5, 2, 'Papas x2'),
(6, 2, 'Papas x3'),
(7, 3, 'Refresco x1'),
(8, 3, 'Refresco x2');
INSERT INTO ticket_producto VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 4),
(3, 2, 1),
(4, 3, 2),
(5, 3, 3),
(6, 3, 4),
(7, 4, 6),
(8, 4, 5),
(9, 4, 1);
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta +1

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la solucion a mi problema, tal vez hay una forma mas facil y rapida pero les comparto la solucion

```
SELECT cp.id, cp.nombre, prods.productos, prods.cant FROM categorias_producto AS cp 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS productos, p.id, p.id_categoria, SUM(tpx.cantidad) as cant FROM producto AS p
         INNER JOIN
            (SELECT COUNT(tp.id) AS cantidad, tp.id_producto FROM ticket_producto AS tp GROUP BY tp.id_producto ) AS tpx ON tpx.id_producto = p.id
         GROUP BY p.id_categoria ) AS prods ON prods.id_categoria = cp.id
WHERE cp.id > 1
```

Me arroja los siguientes datos que ya comprobe que la suma es la correcta de los productos de la tabla ticket

```
id | nombre       | productos | cant
-------------------------------------
2  | Dogos        | 5         | 375
3  | Hamburguesas | 6         | 330
4  | Papas        | 6         | 244
5  | Bebidas      | 1         | 1
```